# Incorrect Redux action for API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

That is my **store.js**:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import mainReducer from './reducers/index';
import fetchJokes from './actions/jokes';
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

const store = createStore(
  mainReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware
  )
)
store
  .dispatch(fetchJokes(1))
  .then(() => console.log(store.getState()))

export default store
```

and that`s my **/actions/jokes.js**

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
import { REQUEST_JOKES, RECEIVE_JOKES } from '../types/jokes'

/*synchronous actions*/

export const requestJokes = quantity => ({
  type: REQUEST_JOKES,
  quantity
});

export const receiveJokes = data => ({
  type: RECEIVE_JOKES,
  jokes: data.value.map(j => j.joke)
});

/*asynchronous actions*/

export const fetchJokes = quantity => {
  return dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestJokes(quantity))
    return fetch('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${quantity}')
      .then(response => response.json(),
        error => console.log('An error: ', error))
      .then(data => dispatch(receiveJokes(data)))
  }
}
```

And console brings me an error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jokes2.default) is not a function` . I've investigated the problem with an action `fetchJokes` but what is the actual problem with this function I cant recognize.

Comment: and I don't understand how do you get 2 then() calls ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda `then` returns new promise. So you could chain as many `then` calls as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using named export for `fetchJokes` so you should import it like this

```
import { fetchJokes } from './actions/jokes';
```

Comment: also you don't have to use /index in your imports. you can ignore index